# Flutter, How to send messages with Twilio without Twilio SDK

Tags: flutter, dart, twilio, sms, twilio-api

Developing in Flutter and you want to send sms to users. This is how you can send out sms with out Twilio Package.

Answer (score 3):

add HTTP package to your pubspec.yml `http: ^0.12.1`
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

`http.Response _sendSms = await http.post('https://[ACCOUNT_SID]:[AUTH_TOKEN]@api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/[ACCOUNT_SID]/Messages.json', body: {'Body': 'You have a user contact us message from app. SUBJECT: "${_subjectController.text}"', 'From': '[TWILLIO_NUMBER]', 'To': '[RECIPIENT_NUMBER]'});`

Validate:
`if(_sendSms.statusCode == 201) { // DO SOMETHING ON SUCCESS  }`